# Complex curveintegral, singularities inside the set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

I've just begun doing complex curve integrals using Cauchys theorem, and there is one thing i dont really understand.

The exercise if following:

Compute $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{z}$ where $\gamma$ is the unit circle oriented counterclockwise.

My solution is using Cauchys theorem:

$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz$ if i know that im working with a open set $G$

I know that $f(a)=1$ so that gets me that $\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz=2\pi i$ which is the correct answer without taking into account the singularity.

My question is, how does the singularity point $0$ plays its role here? Am i calculating this wrong, or how do i use the Theroem when there is singularities within the set $G$?

Comment: If you calculate the integral with residue theorem, since $z=0$ is a simple pole, you obtain $Res  f(z) = lim z \to 0  (\frac{z}{z}) = 1$ and the value of integral $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z} = 2πi(1)$ in this way you can verify the fact.

Comment: Im afraid we havent learned about the residue theorem yet in class

Comment: Actually the above comment signify the importance of the singularity in calculating the value of integral

Comment: I understand, is there anyway to get a better understanding of singularities inside our set without knowing residue theorem?

Comment: What exactly is your question here? Evaluating the integral ?

Comment: My question is, how does the singularity point matter when calculating this integral? Since the we cant use $z=0$ in $\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z}$ Or have i missunderstood the theorem? Is the singularity only for the function $f(z)=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, $f(z)=1$ is a constant function.  Notice that $f$ is the numerator of the integrand.

Comment: Does it matter that $0$ is a singularity for the original integral $\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z}dz$? Or does the singularities only matter for $f(z)$?

Comment: @zzz__ The integral $\int_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a} \textrm{d}z$ always has a singularity at $z=a$.  The hypothesis of Cauchy's theorem is that $f$ be holomorphic on a simply connected domain containing $\gamma$, so $f$ shouldn't have any singularities for this to work.  I think you are confused because you are "starting" with $\int_C \frac{1}{z} \textrm{d}z$ and you are not seeing how you are applying the theorem.  We are taking $f(z) = 1$ and $a=0$.  Try this integral as another example:  $\int_\gamma \frac{z^3+1}{z-2}$ where $\gamma$ is a small circle around $2$.

Comment: Oh, how i understand. Thanks for explaining!